# Cambiar valor de una variable en Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo una variable que por defecto inicializa en 0, después a través de un evento estoy  obteniendo la duración de un vídeo el cual viene a ser el nuevo valor de la variable, Pero al imprimirlo ésta no cambia.
Comparto mi código

```
var transicion = 0;
function siguiente() {
    $interval.cancel($scope.intervalo);
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        transicion = parseInt(video.duration) * 1000;
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log(transicion) //aqui se imprime bien
    });
    console.log(transicion)//aqui el valor es 0
    $scope.intervalo = $interval(function(){ 
        siguiente();
    }, transicion);
}
```

En sí el código lo que permite es mostrar un div de acuerdo a un intervalo que va junto al valor transición, lo que hago con ello es que si tengo un vídeo primero obtengo la duración y el intervalo durara de acuerdo a la duración del mismo. Espero y puedan ayudarme de antemano muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

El evento `loadedmetadata` no se ejecuta de forma lineal. Por lo que al momento del evento ejecutarse, ya el proceso de imprimir la variable ha pasado.

Si necesitas el valor actualizado de la variable, tendras que ejecutar el metodo `$interval` dentro del evento:

```
function siguiente() {
    $interval.cancel($scope.intervalo);
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
        transicion = parseInt(video.duration) * 1000;
        $scope.$apply();

        $scope.intervalo = $interval(function(){ 
            siguiente();
        }, transicion);

    });
}
```

Comment: Ya lo intente pero no funciona

Comment: Que pasa cuando lo haces asi? Si quieres ayuda tienes que ser mas claro en lo que dices, de lo contrario no hay forma de ayudarte.